# Membase Blocking on Key Eviction?

Tags: sqlite, blocking, membase

We've been using Memcached for a while and recently started testing Membase in AWS. We're testing a single instance of Membase 1.6.0 on a large EC2 instance with 5GB RAM, 750GB disk (Linux FC8).

We've noticed that SQLite seems to block on eviction purges on an hourly basis when expiryPagerSleeptime wakes up. Although this was expected (because SQLite uses database level locking), we didn't expect that Membase would block as well.

In this case, it seems that while SQLite is deleting old keys, Membase "operations per second" fall to zero or near zero for several minutes. After the eviction process has finished, the Membase server quickly recovers. I would have anticipated that reads from Membase RAM would still proceed while SQLite was locked but this doesn't seem to be the case. Everything stops; the spy clients throw streams of exceptions as they time-out waiting for data that never arrives.

My impression from the docs was that Membase was asynchronous and would continue to serve reads from RAM. I would appreciate any help or suggestions to prevent Membase from blocking on key evictions. This is a serious issue for us because it seems to take about 4 minutes for this eviction process to finish and for the backlog in the disk queue to clear. That means every hour, Membase is effectively offline for 4 minutes.

I should also mention that this happens once the data is larger than RAM (and it's increasing size on the disk). We didn't notice any issues with key eviction when the data was just in RAM (presumably because key eviction in RAM happens too quickly to be noticable.)

Answer (score 1):

With the desire of not duplicating information, this question is being answered and explained here: http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/membase-blocking-key-eviction

Perry